# How to save MarkLogic data in csv file using xdmp:save

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to generate csv file. Code below creates csv file, but it fails to append data row per new line.

Am I missing anything?

Here is the code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $filename := "D:\csv-reports\test.csv"

let $directory-query := cts:directory-query("/searcdoc/")
let $uris := cts:uris((), (), $directory-query)

for $uri in $uris
let $additional := doc($uri)/searcdoc/access/additional/text()
let $des := doc($uri)/searcdoc/std/text()
let $option := <options xmlns="xdmp:save"><method>text</method></options>
let $results := text{((fn:string-join(($uri, $des, $additional), ",")), "&#10;")}

return

xdmp:save($filename, $results, $option)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to re-arrange the code a bit. Try this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $filename := "D:\csv-reports\test.csv"

let $directory-query := cts:directory-query("/searcdoc/")
let $option := <options xmlns="xdmp:save"><method>text</method></options>
let $uris := cts:uris((), (), $directory-query)
let $lines := 
  for $uri in $uris
  let $additional := doc($uri)/searcdoc/access/additional/text()
  let $des := doc($uri)/searcdoc/std/text()
  return fn:string-join(($uri, $des, $additional), ",")

return
  xdmp:save($filename, text{ fn:string-join($lines, "&#10;") }, $option)
```

---

edited to change `"\n"` to `"&#10;"`

Comment: Thanks that worked i just had to update "\n" to "&#10;" for new line

Comment: The above works, but doesn't scale too well. You'll get further it return each csv line as response, and allowing a http client to capture and write to disk.

Comment: For really scaling solutions you probably should look into [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) or [DMSDK](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk)